# Razor Pages - How to insert a select dropdown value into an asp-route?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a dropdown select with values for rows per page which I'm using in a razor list. The razor list has been configured with pagination, sort and filtering.

The select input here:

```
<div class="col-3 pr-0">
                    <select asp-for="@Model.RowsPerPage" class="form-control" onchange="onChangeRowsPerPageSelect()" id="rowsPerPageSelect">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                        <option value="500">500</option>
                        <option value="1000">1000</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Below is one of the column headers of the list view, which when clicked will call the OnGet in the page model with the associated sort by and filter url.

```
<th>
  <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.NameSort"
    asp-route-rowsPerPage="10"
    asp-route-currentFilter="@Model.CurrentFilter">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TcpServer[0].Name)
  </a>
</th>
```

In the above table header code, you can see that I have hard coded the asp-route-rowsPerPage with value of 10, this works, but what I'm stuck with is how to grab the selected value from the select dropdown box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the select in a form and let it submit onchange event:

```html
<form method="get">
    <select asp-for="@Model.RowsPerPage" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <!-- options... -->
    </select>

    <!-- put other filters inside the form as well -->
</form>
```

Get the `RowsPerPage` value from the model:

```html
<a asp-route-rowsPerPage="@Model.RowsPerPage"
   .
   .
   .>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TcpServer[0].Name)
</a>
```

On the backend you should be using `OnGet()` method and have binding enabled for the `RowsPerPage` :

```cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public int RowsPerPage { get; set; } = 10;

    // Do the same for other filters...

    public void OnGet()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Laz, many thanks for your help. The bit I had missed was to set the RowsPerPage in the page model with the value using "onchange="this.form.submit()"

Comment: <label asp-for="@Model.RecordsPerPageSL"></label>
            <a asp-route-rowsPerPage="@Model.RecordsPerPageId">
            </a>
                <select id="RecordsPerPageDD" asp-for="@Model.RecordsPerPageId" asp-items="@Model.RecordsPerPageSL" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            </select>

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically change the `href` attribute of that link in select's onchange event :

1. Add `id`(or name) attribute for `a` tag :

   ```
   <a  id="testLink" asp-page="./Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.NameSort"
   asp-route-rowsPerPage="10"
   asp-route-currentFilter="@Model.CurrentFilter">
   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TcpServer[0].Name)
   ```
2. In `onchange` event modify the href link :

   ```
   <script>
   function onChangeRowsPerPageSelect() {
       var selectedValue = $("#rowsPerPageSelect").val();

       var url = $("#testLink").attr("href").split('&');
       url[1] = "rowsPerPage=" + selectedValue;
       $("#testLink").attr('href', url.join('&'));
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi Nan, I decided to go for the first answer, but many thanks for your help :)